# How can I track accepted invitation sender on facebook app?

Tags: facebook, invite

Situation: user **A** send invitation to my fb app to his friends **X**, **Y** and **Z**. Users **X** and **Y** has accepted invitations, but user **Z** not.

How can I track haw many users accepted invitations? I want to take some privileges for user A  based on accepted invitations count.

Is there any method to track sender_id when invitation accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother, it's not allowed by [the policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Per section V.1.

> You must not incentivize users to
>   grant additional permissions or use
>   Application Integration Points.

And per the documentation about [Application Integration Points](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#Application%20Integration%20Point)

> By "Application Integration Point" we
>   mean Application Info Section,
>   Application tab, Feed, requests
>   (**including invites**), Publisher,
>   inbox attachments, Chat, Bookmarks, or
>   any other feature of a user profile or
>   Facebook communication channel in
>   which or through which an application
>   can provide, display, or deliver
>   content directed at, on behalf of, or
>   by permission of a user.

Comment: ..which is pretty much bs since the term "incentivize" can mean more or less anything or nothing at all. By inviting a friend and telling him "this is a great app" - right there is the incentive. 
Just another way for FB to maintain their dictatorship.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need to additional permissions.

Using the next value, you can store the referring user id and referred user.

It's simply explained here: http://fbcookbook.ofhas.in/tag/tracking-invitation/

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do this. I'm doing it for other reasons (tracking how people get to the app and other analytics type stuff). In the , you can set the url attribute of the  button. For instance, mine is . That url does some processing that will be saved in my database saying that user with userId 9999 invited the current user. This is being used to tell us the successfulness of invitations (our original idea was incentivization like you, but they pointed that out in the policy too).

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it:

- track the invites by looping over $_GET['to'] on your 'thank you page' and store these IDs (= to_id) against  the current user ID (= from_id) in your DB.
- When a new users signs up, compare the new ID with the to_ids the table. If it's a match, honor the corresponding from_id

Drawback: if somebody was invited by 2 or more ppl you don't know which invitation to honor. I just honor all invitations which makes everybody happy.

Comment: voting down without giving a reason is lame.

Comment: here is the reason why voting down : you are not really tracking that way, you are guessing and that is bad analytics ! because the new user could have came from number of reason not just the invite.

Comment: Maybe read the entire answer before down-voting. The section "Drawback" in my answer covers exactly that.