# tracking invite application facebook

Tags: facebook, tracking, facebook-apps, invite, invitation

I wonder if it is possible to make the tracking of a facebook application: know who invited people to my application

and people who have accepted the invitation

it is possible ca: is what we can integrate the functionality in php?

thank you in advance

Comment: Please read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345428/how-can-i-track-accepted-invitation-sender-on-facebook-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/).